# Excel calculating drop rates

Tags: excel, math

**Goal:**
I want a excel-sheet to calculate the Drop rates for each item, and being able to add more data after every time I've played to make the results more acurate.

**example data:**

*Drop # = howmany times the item has been droped*

*Drop % = the percentage that that item was droped*

[image: data example]

---

The data is in a table, the total value of Drop # is not.
Each Drop# should represent an input, so i can add the quantity droped of each item after i stopped playing.

**Basicly:**
I need the function that i have to put in ea Drop% cell.

Comment: Could you define your variables and equations more clearly? What is "Drop #"? Is it the number of enemies you had to kill before the item dropped, or how many times that item dropped in one play session? Do you then calculate the mean number of enemies before each drop? Why is the "Drop %" for Fragment Lv3 and Gemstone Lv1 more than 100?

Comment: To the moderator: Please ignore my flag, as the last edit has satisfied my objection.

Comment: I want it to stay at the bottom, even if you select to order it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each column's "total" row is just the sum of the cells above it. The formulas should be like so:

```
Cell   Formula
C25    =SUM(C6:C24) 
D25    =SUM(D6:D24)
 . . .
```

Then, each cell in the second column will be overall drop % (for all data). You calculate it by dividing the sum of that row by the sum of all rows:

```
Cell   Formula
B6     =SUM(C6:Z6)/SUM($C$25:$Z$25)
B7     =SUM(C7:Z7)/SUM($C$25:$Z$25)
 . . .
```

The dollar signs are to make the cell references absolute rather than relative, which make it so that Excel leaves that part of the formula alone when you copy/paste the formula to other cells.

You don't actually need to calculate the totals for this - with `B6` for instance, `=SUM(C6/Z6)/SUM($C$6:$Z$24)` would also work. But I'm assuming the totals by themselves might be informative to you, so I left it the way it is.

The `Z` is assuming your data goes up to column `Z`, feel free to alter this if you need more/less columns.

If you need to support an arbitrary number of columns, I think there's a way, but I'm not sure right now - I'm sure you can find it on this site or Google.